# Getting max value from a Date column in Oracle using max()

Tags: oracle

I am trying to query the latest date from table with a column DATE.

My expression is as follow:
SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM table_name;

I received back error:
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:
*Action:

Any idea what is the issue? please help.

Comment: `DATE` is a reserved keyword, and any table cannot have a such column name unless quoted such like `"DATE"` or `"DaTe"` .. vs. (eg. there shouldn't even exist such a column within the table)

Answer (score 0):

`DATE` is a reserved word and cannot be used as an unquoted identifier as the SQL engine expects it to be either a data-type or as part of a date literal such as `DATE '1970-01-01'`. In your case, the SQL engine expects `DATE` to be followed by the literal of the date-literal (e.g. `'1970-01-01'`) but that does not happen which is why it complains about a missing expression.

If you have a column named `DATE` then you should:

1. Change it to a different name; or
2. If that is not possible, always use a quoted identifier whenever you refer to the column (which requires double quotes around the identifier and the correct case to be used).

   ```sql
   SELECT MAX("DATE") FROM table_name;
   ```